# Grupos de episódios são temporadas, grupos de temporadas séries, grupos de séries?

Tags: vocabulário

As séries que passam na televisão são geralmente divididas em episódios. Um conjunto de episódios dá origem a uma temporada. E o conjunto das várias temporadas é designado por série. Estou a afirmar, mas naturalmente aceito correções!

No entanto, há séries que tiveram uma primeira versão no passado (digamos anos 60) e agora voltam a passar. Como designar este conjunto?

E, num contexto próximo, como designar o grupo de filmes com 6 ou 7 edições, como "Velocidade Furiosa" que penso ir no número 7? (Saga?)

Ou filmes como os do James Bond, que se renovam a cada 2 anos?

Comment: Um grupo de séries é "um seriado".

Comment: filmes com várias edições são "filmes com continuações" e cada filme "uma sequência".

Comment: Filmes baseados na mesma trama, são "remakes".

Comment: @Centaurus: eu poderia ter dito que preferia uma resposta para Portugal, mas mesmo no Brasil, pare que não é assim:3. [Brasil]   [Cinema, Televisão]  Obra televisiva ou cinematográfica dividida em episódios, geralmente difundidos com intervalos regulares. (Equivalente no português de Portugal: série.)

"seriado", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/seriado [consultado em 19-01-2018].

Comment: Minhas afirmações acima referem-se àquilo que eu e meus pares usamos.  Por esse motivo são comentários e não respostas.

Comment: Um seriado de televisão tem episódios. Os episódios são por temporada. Game of Thrones temporada 8, ainda não saiu. Que eu saiba, temporada se usa tanto no Brasil quanto em Portugal.

Answer (score 2):

Um grupo de episódios pertencente ao mesmo título denomina-se temporada (de série), um grupo de temporadas nomeia-se série. Um grupo de séries, agora, depende do contexto e da conexão entre essas séries. Se for:

- de séries desrelacionadas — digamos, 'Game of Thrones' e 'The Walking Dead —, diz-se simplesmente séries, entretenimento audiovisual, ou outro substantivo pertinente;
- de séries relacionadas por universo — exempli gratia, 'Arrow' e 'Flash', que passam-se no mesmo universo, o universo de séries DC —, diz-se apenas universo ou realidade;
- de séries relacionadas por universo e tema — verbi gratia, 'Avatar: A Lenda de Aang' e 'Avatar: A Lenda de Korra', que existem no mesmo universo e o segundo servindo de sequência pro primeiro, porém narrando estórias diferentes em períodos de tempo diferentes —, diz-se franquia — "a franquia 'Avatar'";
- de títulos (filmes) pertencentes a uma sequência temática e/ou cronológica, diz-se franquia também — a franquia '007' ou a franquia 'Fast Furious';

OBS: embora um conjunto de filmes em sua totalidade possa ser chamado de franquia, aqueles que resguardam relação cronológica — isto é, pertencem explicitamente ao mesmo universo, e não estão contidos em períodos de tempo extremamente díspares — também podem ser chamados de série de filmes; Fast Furious é uma série de filmes, porém 007 em sua holisticidade não é, pois Golden Eye e Skyfall não se passam na mesma realidade.

Comment: Há algum fundamento para esta terminologia? A única razão para utilizar franquia, que eu descubra, prende-se com a associação (sonora) entre franquia e franchising. Sendo que me parece que a classificação económica é de pouca valia para o nome coletivo.
Que te parece?

Comment: O fundamento foi lógico e popular. A escolha de termos como 'universo' e 'realidade' dispensam explicações de raciocínio para os exemplos escolhidos, além de serem comumente usados para os fins associados no texto. Da mesma forma, franquia é utilizada por uso popular; entretanto, franquia provém — assim como o franchise do inglês — do francês 'franchise', originário do francês medieval (http://www.mundodasfranquias.com.br/a-origem-do-nome-franquia/). É provável que o vocábulo haja tido o significado estendido para hoje oferecer a denotação de franquia de midia.

Comment: Fonte para franquia de midia: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franquia_de_m%C3%ADdia
Com efeito que nenhuma das fontes é absolutamente confiável, porém basta pesquisar em alternativas que confirmam-se as informações.